# Present native ios Files app a specific folder from my app

Tags: ios, swift

I have an app say called `MyApp` it is primarily `wkwebview`. It is already integrated to Files app so I can `import/export` files from my `wkwebview` to be able to download files to local machine or upload files to the server.

Finally I am trying to build a `UIbutton` in my app that will allow my users to Jump into Files app in the folder where I am storing all their content. Instead of building a full `FileProviderUI` into my app, I just want the button to take the user into the Files App navigating to the folder.

When I give the path for `UIDocumentInteractionController` to be a directory and do a shared open to present it, nothing happens. No error, nothing at at all. I just want the user to be able to Jump into the folder called `MyApp` inside the Files app.

I thought it will be very simple. Adding a `FileProvider` extension or `FilePRoviderUI` extension seems superflous to just jump the user into this folder and let him interact with Files app to do whatever he likes - open/delete/modify document.

I have to assume that the users are not savvy enough to know even if I tell them that files are saved in Files App for them to be able to interact with directly when they are offline!

```
        let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!    
        // Just jump to the folder forcing Files app to open this                    
        let viewer = UIDocumentInteractionController(documentsUrl)

        viewer.delegate = self
        viewer.presentPreview(animated: true)
```

Nothing gets presented to the user and nothing happens. The button tap just quietly fails.

Comment: Have to implemented  documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview(_:) delegate method?

Comment: Yes I have implemented documentInteractionControllerViewControllerForPreview - I can open a specific document file if I give the path URL of a full file.  It is when I give the path to a folder it just bombs and does nothing.

Comment: 'UIDocumentInteractionController' is only intended to preview a document -> 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidocumentinteractioncontroller/1616828-presentpreview

Comment: I see! .Govind - is there anyway to achieve my goal to opening the Files App or present MyApp folder for the user?

Comment: This can be useful -> https://www.appcoda.com/files-app-integration/

Comment: Not exactly - my app is really a webview app - practically a single view. I think what you are saying maybe is I need rootview and an additional documentview controller ; which is all possible (even with Fileui extensions) but seems excessive or superflous for what I want!

Answer (score 5):

I think I figured this out.  There is a specific URL format that will automatically open the Files app it is shareddocuments:// - Here is a simple function that seems to achieve this quiet simply.

```
    func openSharedFilesApp() {
    let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let sharedurl = documentsUrl.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "shareddocuments://")
    let furl:URL = URL(string: sharedurl)!
    UIApplication.shared.open(furl, options: convertToUIApplicationOpenExternalURLOptionsKeyDictionary([:]), completionHandler: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Adding to @Vijay's answer in **iOS 15, Swift 5**:

```
let documentsUrl =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
let sharedurl = documentsUrl.absoluteString.replacingOccurrences(of: "file://", with: "shareddocuments://")
let furl:URL = URL(string: sharedurl)!
if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(furl) {
    UIApplication.shared.open(furl, options: [:])
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, Vijay. Here it is in Objective-C.

```
- (void) openSharedFilesApp
{
    NSArray<NSString *>* directories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);     // yes = expand tilde
    NSURL* url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:directories.firstObject];
    NSString* sharedDocumentPath = [url.absoluteString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"file://" withString:@"shareddocuments://"];
    NSURL* sharedDocumentURL = [NSURL URLWithString:sharedDocumentPath];
    [UIApplication.sharedApplication openURL:sharedDocumentURL options:@{UIApplicationOpenURLOptionUniversalLinksOnly: @(NO)} completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    }];
}
```